# Symfony2 Why Doctrine remove my element when I remove it from the collection?

Tags: symfony, collections, doctrine

Given I have 2 entities, **Post** and **Comment**

My relations are :

Post

```
oneToMany:
    comments:
        targetEntity: Comment
        mappedBy: post
        orphanRemoval: false
        cascade: [ persist ]
        fetch: EXTRA_LAZY
```

Comment

```
manyToOne:
    post:
        targetEntity: Post
        joinColumn:
            name: post_id
            referencedColumnName: id
            onDelete: SET NULL
```

Now in my controller, whenever I want to manually remove a comment from a post, Doctrine also deletes my comment from database.

```
public function testAction()
{
    $postRepository = $this->getDoctrine()
                   ->getManager()
                   ->getRepository('MyBundle:Post');

    $post = $postRepository ->find(1);

    $commentRepository = $this->getDoctrine()
                   ->getManager()
                   ->getRepository('MyBundle:Comment');

    $comment = $commentRepository ->find(1);

    /* My comment is a child of the post */
    $post->removeComment($comment);    
}


/* Entity/Post */
public function removeComment(Comment $comment)
{
     $this->comments->removeElement($comment);
}
```

By doing that, my comment is deleted from the database, I don't get it.

PS : I found a solution to avoid doctrine deleting my entity which is :

```
foreach($post->getComments() as $_comment) {
    if ($commment === $_comment) {
        $post->removeComment($comment);
    }
}
```

In that case Doctrine didn't deleted my comment and just removed the relation as I want.
Anyone can explain me please ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe in the second scenario, there is no persist/flush after removing?